# soap C# connection in WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

My problem is that I have a WSDL for a Java webService invoked from C#.

It has a `service.doWork()` parameter that gets the service request and using Wireshark I can see that it sends the tag:

```
< soap:body > and </ soap:body >
```

in the xml.

The problem is that the webservice expects the tag

```
< soapenv:body >
```

so it throws an exception stating that **the soapenv is an undeclared prefix**.

I cant modify the web service, I just need to change  in the request message to `<soapenv:body>`.

Comment: Could we see the code for the service.doWork() method?

Comment: If the service expects a particular prefix, then it is horribly broken, and should not be used, under any circumstances. That would mean that it was written by people who do not understand XML at all. The prefix doesn't matter: the prefix is an abbreviation of the namespace. If the two namespaces match, then the prefix is not relevant. Any code that expects a particular prefix is simply wrong.

Comment: i know that but i must use this service